# Using a timer to do a specific task at 4pm

Tags: c#, winforms

What I'm trying to do is use a timer to keep checking the current time. Once the condition is met. (It's 4pm) then I want to play an audio file. Finally the timer should then stop and nothing should happen until the very next day.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     const double interv = 1000; 
     System.Timers.Timer xtime = new System.Timers.Timer(interv);

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         xtime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
         xtime.Enabled = true;
     }


     public void xtime _Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {

         DateTime reach = new DateTime(2016, 5, 8, 11, 58, 0);
         DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

         if (target.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Your time is up.  GOODBYE");
             xtime.Stop();
             xtime .Enabled = false;
         }
     }
 }
```

With the preceding code nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are several timer classes in the .NET framework. For a WinForms app, I would use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. However, to make it work with `System.Timers.Timer`, you probably want to set `AutoReset` to true. See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

Comment: With the following code the message box doesn't even show once though...

Comment: Why would it? The timer only fires once, one second after you start it. The target time is not reached, so the handler doesn't show the message.